# Is it alright if I use 'org.apache.http.legacy' and continue using deprecated stuffs like NameValuePair and others?

Tags: android, apache, deprecated, ccavenue, basicnamevaluepair

I am trying to integrate CCAvenue payment gateway onto my android application. For that, I downloaded their integration kit and used it. But, the kit that is available currently imports org.apache.http and uses its functionalities like httppost, namevaluepair, etc. So, my question is, as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html), is it alright to make below mentioned changes in the gradle and continue using deprecated libraries?

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: if their kit is using that then there is no option for you so you can use legacy.

Answer (score -1):

Put this code snippet in ServiceHandler class , you don''t need to use legacy. You can change their code as per your requirement those are just samples.

```
/**
 *
 * @param postUrl
 * @param postParams
 * @return response in string
 */
public static String makeServiceCall(final String postUrl, final Map<String, String> postParams) {
    Log.e("URL#",postUrl);
    StringBuilder responseBuilder  = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        final URL mUrl = new URL(postUrl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android-4.0.3; en-us; Galaxy Nexus Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) CrMo/16.0.912.75 Mobile Safari/535.7");
        conn.connect();
        conn.setReadTimeout(180000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(180000);
        final OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(postParams));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        final int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                responseBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            responseBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseBuilder.append(e.getMessage());
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseBuilder.append(e.getMessage());
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    } finally {
        if (null != conn) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    System.gc();
    return responseBuilder.toString();
}


/**
 * @Param: map , takes in value in key val format
 */
private static String getQuery(final Map<String, String> mPostItems) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    final Set<String> mKeys = mPostItems.keySet();
    for (String key : mKeys) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(mPostItems.get(key), "UTF-8"));
        Log.e("Key#",key+"#"+mPostItems.get(key));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "Put this code snippet in ServiceHandler"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.